# How to handle case for buffers which are out of range in OpenCl?

Tags: opencl

OpenCl kernel Code:

```
__kernel void calc(__global double* arr1, __global double* arr2, __global double* arr3)
{
    int g = get_global_id(0);
    if (g > 6400) {
        return;
    }

    arr1[g] = arr3[g] * 10.0;
    arr2[g] = arr3[g] * 20.0
}
```

Workgroup size: 6400

This kernel will solve, arr1 and arr2 using arr3. **But issue is arr2 is only size of 3200.** Hence, this will not work. How to handle case for buffers which are out of range in OpenCl?

I can think using condition statement. But i do not want any if-else statement, like:

```
__kernel void calc(__global double* arr1, __global double* arr2, __global double* arr3)
{
    int g = get_global_id(0);
    if (g > 6400) {
        return;
    }

    arr1[g] = arr3[g] * 10.0;

    if (g < 3200) {
        arr2[g] = arr3[g] * 20.0
    }
}
```

I also do not want to add any dummy buffer or extra buffer in arr2, which will increase my buffer size.

How, can i handle such scenarios in OpenCl? Any help/suggestions/links will be appreciated.

Comment: Your solution seems sound. Why do you question it? Do you fear it adds thread divergence? It won't, since within a work-group it is very likely that the condition will be the same.

Comment: @Dithermaster i also think that this solution will work better for me.. but in my case, arrays can be more to calculate of different array size.. adding those many if-else, i thought might not be a feasible way.. Is there any way i can handle such scenarios in opencl?

Comment: If this gets to complicated then just use different kernels. On very recent hardware they can even execute in parallel. But as said by Dithermaster, I would not worry about that too much. Also, what exactly do you expect? OpenCL C is regular C99 which itself cannot do wonders in these scenarios.

Comment: that explains all.. i had tried everything i know. i was just looking for anything that i might be missing. if not, then i am convinced.